# count occurences of number entered by the user

Tags: python, input, count

I need to count the occurrence of the min number from input that has been entered by the user. this is what i have so far, it is displaying the max and min numbers but i don't know how to count the occurrences using ELIF e.g the smallest number occurs 'x' times' 
only a beginner at Python, please help

```
max = 0
min = 0
count_l = 0 
count_s = 0

while True:
    inp = raw_input ("Enter a number\n: ")
    if inp == '0': break
    try:
        num = float (inp)
    except:
        print 'Please enter a valid number'
        continue
    if min == 0 or num < min:
        min = num

    if max == 0 or num > max:
        max = num

def result (max, min):
    print ('Largest Number Entered\n:') , max
    print ('Smallest Number Entered\n:'), min
    print ('Occurence of largest number is: '), count_l
    print ('Occurence of smallest number is: '), count_s

result (max, min)
```

Comment: This code has syntax errors; please correct them.

Comment: Are they fixed now? :/

Answer (score 1):

Well, you change the smallest number dynamically. This means that the count should be reset every time you change the number. The same goes for the maximum number.

Example

```
max = float("-inf")
min = float("inf")
count_l = 0
count_s = 0

def safecast(cast_type, value, default=None):
    try:
        default = cast_type(value)
    finally:
        return default

def input_until(prompt, cast_type, value, default=None):
    while True:
        ret = safecast(cast_type, raw_input(prompt), default=default)
        if ret != value:
            yield ret
        else:
            break

for num in input_until("Enter a number\n:", float, 0):
    if num != 0:
        if num < min:
            min = num
            count_s = 1
        elif num > max:
            max = num
            count_l = 1
        elif num == min:
            count_s += 1
        elif num == max:
            count_l += 1

def result(max, min):
    print('Largest Number Entered:') , max
    print('Smallest Number Entered:'), min
    print('Occurance of largest number is: '), count_l
    print('Occurance of smallest number is: '), count_s

result (max, min)
```

Also, in the future, don't use variables called "max" or "min" because these are python builtin functions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!! this isn't running for me correctly as I need to display the largest number, concurrence of largest number, smallest number, and occurrence of smallest number. The smallest number is displaying as None, with both counts equating to 1 each even when the smallest/largest number are entered multiple times :/

Comment: That's not the case for me. I've updated the code in the past few minutes. Try it again. https://i.gyazo.com/5d1226475b9a8e314205b87821a73260.png

Comment: That did work and thank you! I am a beginner though and just for my own understanding what should i have put for the ELIF option? as that is the method i've been learning and have more of a grasp on that then some of your code, no offence :P

Answer (score 0):

Just use some convenient data structure like a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (possibly, [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) is a better data type to be used as dictionary keys compared to `float`):

```
from decimal import Decimal
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(Decimal)

while True:
    inp = raw_input ("Enter a number\n: ")
    if inp == '0': break
    try:
        num = Decimal(inp)
    except:
        print 'Please enter a valid number'
        continue
    d(num) += 1

items = sorted(d.items())

min_val, min_occurrences = items[0] 
max_val, max_occurrences = items[-1]
```

Comment: Tracking *all* of the input when only the extremes are needed is a bit inefficient.

Comment: To be honest I just need guidance on how to transition the elif option to show the occurrences, i'm new to programming and these basics are about as comfortable as i am within the subject :L